# Runtime error 999 when trying to use cuda with pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I installed Cuda 10.1 and the latest Nvidia Driver for my Geforce 2080 ti. I try to run a basic script to test if pytorch is working and I get the following error:

`RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (999) : unknown error at ..\aten\src\THC\THCGeneral.cpp:50`

Below is the code im trying to run:

```
import torch
torch.cuda.current_device()
torch.cuda.is_available()
torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)
```

Comment: Which `torch.__version__`?

Comment: torch version 1.3.0

Comment: Can you run `nvidia-smi` successfully? This setup should work. BTW, for completeness, can you provide the driver version (you can get it from `nvidia-smi`)?

Comment: I opened cmd as admin and ran nvidia-smi i got a message saying it failed because it couldnt communicate with the nvidia driver. I already updated to the most recent driver 440.97. Opening the device manager I found this: Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)

Comment: Reinstalling the Nvidia driver now.

Comment: pytorch doesn't use the system cuda, it installs its own version locally. Make sure to install the correct version using the command on the pytorch website. To see the version being used with your current install you can print the results of `torch.version.cuda` in your current environment.

Comment: @jodag this is only true if you install using conda, isn't it? If this is also true for the other installation methods, would you mind to provide a reference?

Comment: @Berriel Also true for pip. At least on Linux I can verify this is true. I imagine it's probably also true for Windows. The result of `torch.version.cuda` should tell us more.

Comment: @jodag interesting... I always thought only the conda-based installation would ship its own CUDA, but [apparently not](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/getting-cuda-version-9-0-17-but-nvcc-shows-the-cuda-version-to-be-10-0-130/48300/2).

Comment: For me this error occurs when my Laptop went to sleep mode before. Restarting solved the problem.

Comment: If anyone is interested, I also had this error in windows and got the same output from nvidia-smi.  I had installed CUDA 10.2 with it's corresponding driver and somehow this driver wasn't working right.  Reinstalling the latest nvidia (441.41) driver fixed this problem for me.

Comment: I've also seen this error using Ubuntu 18.04 with Driver Version: 440.44 CUDA Version: 10.2 in a Conda installation of PyTorch AFTER my laptop revives from sleep. Given my RTX 2070 (laptop) + Linux, NVidia's website does not offer me driver version 441.41.

Comment: I should add that `nvidia-smi` still works fine and it appears Chrome is still using the driver for rendering.

Answer (score 15):

Restarting my computer fixed this for me.

But for a less invasive fix, you can also try this solution (from a [tensorflow issue thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5777#issuecomment-301058363)):

```
sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm
sudo rmmod nvidia
sudo modprobe nvidia
sudo modprobe nvidia_uvm
```

Comment: How to fix this on windows, any idea?

Comment: This does not work for me because `rmmod nvidia`  gives the following error: `rmmod: ERROR: Module nvidia is in use by: nvidia_modeset
`

Comment: `rmmod nvidia_uvm` and `modprobe nvidia_uvm` did the trick.

Answer (score 11):

In case of PyTorch it seems to be sufficient to restart only `nvidia-uvm` (Unified Virtual Memory) with

```
sudo modprobe --remove nvidia-uvm  # same as `rmmod`
sudo modprobe nvidia-uvm
```

If that doesn't work, go ahead and restart the whole module with additional `modprobe (--remove) nvidia` as mentioned [@matwilso's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59796570/2687601).

Comment: Thanks! Although it should be modprobe (missing an e).

Comment: It works! (P.S.: remember to reboot your computer if you (re)installed nvidia driver, even your graphical user interface may look OK after restarting your desktop manager(like lightdm).)

Comment: Thanks... But why does this work? What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I solved the 999 error with:
`nvidia-modprobe -u`

Comment: This does not work for me because this is not a known command ...

Comment: I installed `nvidia-modprobe` using `apt-get install` and your solution worked. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling NVIDIA driver solves this problem in my case. (You don't need to restart the computer)